# comand cat ${i} doesn't read the file that i need

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to read some files using `cat ${i}` with `i` being 1 through n(basically I dont know how many files I will have) but it doesn't work. 
Any ideas why?

ex1:

```
cat ${1}   #works
```

ex2:

```
i=1
cat ${i}   #doesnt work
```

Comment: Well if you have a file called 1, this should work. Concerning `${1}`, it's a special variable in bash which indicates the first argument passed to a program. You also don't need the curly braces, just `"$1"` and `"$i"` should work fine (it is also usually good practice to put quotes around variables names, if they can have spaces in them)

Comment: Are you looking to `cat` all the files passed to your script as arguments? If so you can use `cat "$@"`, where `"$@"` will expand to `"$1" "$2" [...] "$n"`

Comment: In principle you can do sth. like: for i in {1..2}; do cat $i; done and instead of 2 set your number ...